# Shift-arrow keys send ABCD in Git Bash in VS Code integrated terminal (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, git-bash, mintty

I am using git bash through the VS Code integrated terminal. I want to use `shift` and the left/right arrow keys to select text. This feature used to be working but broke for me recently, and I can't identify why. Arrow keys work fine for moving the cursor, but in combination with `shift` they produce ABCD characters rather than selecting the text. Using `shift-ctrl-arrow key` (which should select whole words) also produces ABCD characters.

In standalone git bash, shift+arrow keys has no effect, so I suspect it might be a VS Code feature that isn't functioning correctly.
I am using git for Windows version 2.38.1.windows.1 (with mintty) and VS Code version 1.73.1. I am using default settings for VS Code's terminal. My `$TERM` variable in the integrated terminal is `xterm-256color`.

#### What I've tried

I've tried everything I can find Googling this issue:

[Shift-arrow keys send ABCD in Git Bash on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1554895/shift-arrow-keys-send-abcd-in-git-bash-on-windows-10): tried reinstalling git (and VS Code), my `ALT` key is not pressed

[arrow keys no longer scroll in less in Windows Terminal (comment)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3657#issuecomment-1028037890): tried this even though I'm not using Windows Terminal. Adding `export MSYS=enable_pcon` to `~/.bashrc` did not change anything.

[How can I make ctrl+right/left arrow jump words in Visual Studio Code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336382/how-can-i-make-ctrlright-left-arrow-jump-words-in-visual-studio-code/345574): I'm not on MacOS, but I still tried changing keybindings in VS Code. I added this to `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "shift+left",
    "command": "cursorLeftSelect",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

This has no effect; neither does `cursorWordLeftSelect` for `shift+ctrl+left`. Changing `command` to `workbench.action.terminal.kill` does have an effect, so I know VS Code is registering the key combination.

All told, I'm completely stuck on this issue. I clearly remember this feature working, and I can't figure out what changed. Tips/guidance appreciated.